# Agrupación de atributos

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente lista

```
GroupDTO g = groupService.getCriteriosBusqueda(codIdGrupo);

            List<String> listaCriterios = new ArrayList<String>();

            List<GroupDTO> list = g.getListGroupSon();

            for(GroupDTO i : list){

                listaCriterios.add("Tipo regla: " + i.getTipoRegla() + ", Valor: " + i.getRegla());
            }

            groupService.exportCriteriaToCSV(listaCriterios);
```

Que lo que hace es coger una serie de criterios para exportarlos a CSV.
El problema esta en que lo que quiero realizar es agrupar una serie de criterios en base a un código que me separe los criterios que tengan el mismo código.

Lo que quiero es que los que tengan el `codigo agrupacion` igual me salgan separados de los otros,como si fuesen grupos.

Comment: ¿A que llamas exactamente separados?

Comment: A que hay una salto de linea, por ejemplo. O sea en este caso que salgan las 3 primeras lineas luego haya un espacio en blanco y salgan las otras 3 y asi. @JDev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si con un Map de List de objetos Group, como te muestro a continuación:

```
    HashMap<String, List<GroupDTO>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, List<GroupDTO>>();

    List<String> listaCriterios = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<GroupDTO> list = new ArrayList<GroupDTO>();

    GroupDTO grupo4 = new GroupDTO();
    grupo4.setTipoRegla("c");
    grupo4.setRegla("c1");
    grupo4.setCodigoAgrupacion("111002");
    list.add(grupo4);

    GroupDTO grupo2 = new GroupDTO();
    grupo2.setTipoRegla("a");
    grupo2.setRegla("a2");
    grupo2.setCodigoAgrupacion("111000");
    list.add(grupo2);

    GroupDTO grupo3 = new GroupDTO();
    grupo3.setTipoRegla("b");
    grupo3.setRegla("b1");
    grupo3.setCodigoAgrupacion("111001");
    list.add(grupo3);

    GroupDTO grupo5 = new GroupDTO();
    grupo5.setTipoRegla("c");
    grupo5.setRegla("c2");
    grupo5.setCodigoAgrupacion("111002");
    list.add(grupo5);

    GroupDTO grupo1 = new GroupDTO();
    grupo1.setTipoRegla("a");
    grupo1.setRegla("a1");
    grupo1.setCodigoAgrupacion("111000");
    list.add(grupo1);

    GroupDTO grupo6 = new GroupDTO();
    grupo6.setTipoRegla("c");
    grupo6.setRegla("c3");
    grupo6.setCodigoAgrupacion("111002");
    list.add(grupo6);

    String codigoAgrupacion= null;
    List<GroupDTO> nuevaList = null;

    for(GroupDTO grupo : list){

        codigoAgrupacion = grupo.getCodigoAgrupacion();

        if (!hashMap.containsKey(codigoAgrupacion)) {
            nuevaList = new ArrayList<GroupDTO>();
            nuevaList.add(grupo);

            hashMap.put(codigoAgrupacion, nuevaList);
        } else {
            hashMap.get(codigoAgrupacion).add(grupo);
        }       



    }       


    List<GroupDTO> listaTemporal = null;


    Iterator it = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        listaTemporal = (List<GroupDTO>)pair.getValue();
        for(GroupDTO grupoTemporal : listaTemporal){
            listaCriterios.add("Tipo regla: " + grupoTemporal.getTipoRegla() + ", Valor: " + grupoTemporal.getRegla()+", Código Agrupación:"+grupoTemporal.getCodigoAgrupacion());

        }
        listaCriterios.add("-----------------------------------------------------");
    }        


    for(String cadena: listaCriterios){
        System.out.println(cadena);
    }
```

Resultado:

```
Tipo regla: b, Valor: b1, Código Agrupación:111001
-----------------------------------------------------
Tipo regla: a, Valor: a2, Código Agrupación:111000
Tipo regla: a, Valor: a1, Código Agrupación:111000
-----------------------------------------------------
Tipo regla: c, Valor: c1, Código Agrupación:111002
Tipo regla: c, Valor: c2, Código Agrupación:111002
Tipo regla: c, Valor: c3, Código Agrupación:111002
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Y alguna otra opción si tener que crear los grupos, ya que a veces tengo un montón de registros y no puedo crearlos manualmente, gracias por la respuesta

Comment: @Stewie, los DTO's yo solo los generé a manera de ejemplo tratando de emular los datos que pones,  ya que no se que te regresa tu función: `GroupDTO g = groupService.getCriteriosBusqueda(codIdGrupo);` Es decir tu generas tus GroupDTO con los datos que más te convengan.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no tengo un IDE para probarlo ni nada pero veamos si es esto lo que quieres:

```
GroupDTO g = groupService.getCriteriosBusqueda(codIdGrupo);

List<String> listaCriterios = new ArrayList<String>();

List<GroupDTO> list = g.getListGroupSon();

valorAnterior = 111000; //Declaralo arriba donde gustes, usando el primer valor

for(GroupDTO i : list){

    listaCriterios.add("Tipo regla: " + i.getTipoRegla() + ", Valor: " + i.getRegla());

    if (i.getCodigo() != valorAnterior){
         //Salto de línea
         valorAnterior = i.getCodigo();
    }

}

groupService.exportCriteriaToCSV(listaCriterios);
```

Se me hace muy cutre pero bueno, siento no tener más tiempo para especificarlo mejor. El salto de línea según como realices la exportación puede ser un elemento más de la lista en blanco.